# liblabjackusb.so: undefined symbol: DigitalIO

Tags: python-2.7, shared-libraries, ubuntu-16.04

I got an installation and library issue for the LabJack product https://labjack.com/products/u12

I followed these installation steps for an installation on ubuntu 16.04.
https://labjack.com/support/software/installers/exodriver/mac-and-linux/in-depth-build-instructions

The following code brings me to an undefined symbol for DigitalIO in the liblabjackusb.so

```
$ python
>>> import u12
>>> d =u12.U12()
>>> d.digitalIO(idNum=-1, demo=0, trisD=3, trisIO=0, stateD=0, stateIO=0, updateDigital=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/u12.py", line 2506, in digitalIO
def getFirmwareVersion(self, idNum=None):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 375, in __getattr__
func = self.__getitem__(name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 380, in __getitem__
func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: /usr/local/lib/liblabjackusb.so: undefined symbol: DigitalIO
```

I was looking around for the DigitalIO implementation and i found it in ljacklm.h and ljacklm.c.

```
$cd ljacklm/libljacklm
$ nm ljacklm.o | grep DigitalIO
0000000000007489 T DigitalIO
$ nm libljacklm.so.1.20.2 | grep DigitalIO
00000000000091a9 T DigitalIO
```

This shows that the lib was generated correctly.

How come u12.py loads the liblabjackusb.so since it does not have the DigitalIO function declaration and implementation ?
(see u12.py line 348) . Should the function _loadLinuxSo() load libljacklm.so instead of liblabjackusb.so !?

It this a bug ?

Did anyone encounter this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and I found a post on the Labjack website that should answer your question.

https://labjack.com/forums/u12/liblabjackusbso-undefined-symbol-digitalio

Essentially U12 support was added before libjacklm.so was implemented.
They suggest a workaround using rawDIO.

Comment: Great. I've opened a bug issue on their github project.